# Are HTML entities necessary for anything besides escaping?

Tags: html, encoding

Obviously `&lt;` and `&gt;` are necessary for escaping user input. But is there any reason to use, say, `&trade;` instead of ™?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This is usually a product of people confused about either encoding or their OS's input methods.  If you use a modern encoding (e.g. UTF-8) and learn how to type special characters, you'll very rarely have to go beyond `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`.  For instance, with the [Compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), entering ™ usually requires just Compose-t-m.

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016080/why-are-html-character-entities-necessary/1016089#1016089) on this.