# Why is encoding of HTML special characters neccessarry?

Tags: html, utf-8, html-encode

I'm sure the answer is trivial (or some historic, legacy reason) but I'm wondering **why do we need to encode HTML special characters like €, ä in html** if browser can display them as they are. Of course characters like <, >, ', " must be encoded/escaped as they represent starting of html tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    &lt; <!-- this must be encoded as < represents a start of a html tag-->
    € <!-- why does this symbol needs to be html encoded, as browser with utf-8 charset displays it ok -->  
    파일 선택 <!-- not html encoded, as is -->
    ä -> &#228;
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Related questions:

- [Are HTML entities necessary for anything besides escaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059015/are-html-entities-necessary-for-anything-besides-escaping)
- [Why are HTML character entities necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016080/why-are-html-character-entities-necessary/1016089#1016089)

Comment: Note that even if your web page looks right with special characters, when a preview is generated (like when you paste the link on Facebook or Whatsapp), those characters may look wrong (you get the "Unicode replacement character" � = U+FFFD). In that case, only escaped special characters work. And furthermore, if you use some special characters you may end up changing the encoding of your file to something that uses 2 bytes per character, therefore making it take twice the space.

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need to encode HTML special characters like €, ä in html

You don't, I'm not sure what makes you think you have to. It's just an option, if you prefer writing these in escaped HTML format.

Note that you *do* need to specify the encoding of your HTML page itself somehow, which you've done with the `<meta>` tag in your example. That is what determines what these "extended" characters mean, in this case UTF8 characters.